# NgbModal does not use provided templateUrl

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap

I am following the example in this [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples), but the modal that shows only has `<div class="modal-content">HI</div>` as the template instead of the full HTML template like the demo.

in my component.html:

```
<ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-basic-title">Profile update</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        ...
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Save click')">Save</button>
  </div>
</ng-template>
```

component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html'
})
export class ModalComponent {
  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(content, {ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-basic-title'}).result.then((result) => {
    }, (reason) => {
    });
  }


}
```

Comment: What is the content of `templateUrl: './modal.component.html'` file?

Comment: @WandMaker - I posted that under 'in my component.html'

Comment: Which file contains `<div class="modal-content">HI</div>` ?

Comment: @WandMaker none. There is no such file. That's why I'm confused on what I get.

Comment: It must be there somewhere in your code.  There is no other explanation for this issue